# Postgres ATOMIC stored procedure INSERT INTO . . . SELECT with one parameter and one set of rows from a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a stored procedure to let a dev assign new user identities to a specified group when they don't already have one (i.e. insert a parameter and the output of a select statement into a joining table) without hand-writing every pair of foreign keys as values to do so. I know how I'd do it in T-SQL/SQL Server but I'm working with a preexisting/unfamiliar Postgres database. I would strongly prefer to keep my stored procedures as `LANGUAGE SQL`/`BEGIN ATOMIC` and this + online examples being simplified and/or using constants has made it difficult for me to get my bearings.

Apologies in advance for length, this is me trying to articulate why I do not believe this question is a duplicate based on what I've been able to find searching on my own but I may have overcorrected.

Schema (abstracted from the most identifying parts; these are not the original table names and I am not in a position to change what anything is called; I am also leaving out indexing for simplicity's sake) is like:

```
create table IF NOT EXISTS user_identities (
    id BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [more columns not relevant to this query)
)

create table IF NOT EXISTS user_groups (
    id BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name TEXT NOT NULL
) 

create table IF NOT EXISTS group_identities (
    user_id BIGINT REFERENCES user_identities(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT NOT NULL,
    group_id BIGINT REFERENCES user_groups(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT NOT NULL
)
```

Expected dev behavior:

1. Add all predetermined identities intended to belong to a group in a single batch
2. Add identifying information for the new group (it is going to take a lot of convincing to bring the people involved around to using nested stored procedures for this if I ever can)
3. Bring the joining table up to date accordingly (what I've been asked to streamline).

If this were SQL Server I would do (error handling omitted for time and putting aside whether `EXCEPT` or `NOT IN` would be best for now, please)

```
create OR alter proc add_identities_to_group 
  @group_name varchar(50) NULL
as BEGIN 
declare @use_group_id int 
if @group_name is NULL 
  set @use_group_id = (select Top 1 id from user_groups where id not in (select group_id from group_identities) order by id asc) 
ELSE set @use_group_id = (select id from user_groups where name = @group_name)

insert into group_identities (user_id, group_id) 
  select @use_group_id, id from user_identities 
    where id not in (select user_id from group_identities)
END 
GO
```

Obviously this is not going to fly in Postgres; part of why I want to stick with atomic stored procedures is staying in "neutral" SQL, both to be closer to my comfort zone and because I don't *know* what other languages the database is currently set up for, but my existing education has played kind of fast and loose with differentiating what was T-SQL specific at any point.

I am aware that this is not going to run for a wide variety of reasons because I'm still trying to internalize the syntax, but the bad/conceptual draft I have written so that I have anything to stare at is:

```
create OR replace procedure add_identities_to_groups( 
  group_name text default NULL ) language SQL 
  BEGIN ATOMIC 
    declare use_group_id integer
      if group_name is NULL 
        set use_group_id = (select Top 1 id from user_groups
          where id not in (select user_id from group_identities)
          order by id asc) 
      ELSE set use_group_id = (select id from user_groups where name = group_name) ;
      insert into group_identities (group_id, user_id)
        select use_group_id, id from user_identities
          where id not in (select user_id from group_identities)
  END ; 
GO ;
```

Issues:

- Have not found either answers for how to do this with the combination of a single variable and a column with `BEGIN ATOMIC` or hard confirmation that it wouldn't work (e.g. can atomic stored procedures just not accept parameters? I cannot find an answer to this on my own). (This is part of why existing answers that I can find here and elsewhere haven't been clarifying for me.)
- ~~Don't know how to compensate for Postgres's not differentiating variables and parameters from column names at all. (This is why examples using a hardcoded constant haven't helped, and they make up virtually all of what I can find off StackOverflow itself.)~~ Not a problem if Postgres will handle that intelligently within the atomic block but that's one of the things I hadn't been able to confirm on my own.
- Google results for "vanilla" SQL unpredictably saturated with SQL Server anyway, while my lack of familiarity with Postgres is not doing me any favors but I don't know anyone personally who has more experience than I do.

Comment: "*Don't know how to compensate for Postgres's not differentiating variables and parameters from column names at all.*" - that's easy: don't give parameters the same names as columns. Most people use a prefix for that, e.g. `p_foo`. If you want all statements to run in an "atomic" fashion, just put them into a single transaction.

Comment: I'm not duplicating column names but I haven't been able to test against the database yet and wasn't confident that it wouldn't just error out due to... not being a column name. If that's not a concern I can cross it off in the main post though, sorry.

Comment: 1) Not sure why you want to use `BEGIN ATOMIC`? 2) You can't use `declare` in `sql` language functions 3) You probably want to use [plpgsql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html). 4) See here [Variable substitution](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-VAR-SUBST) for how to deal with variable/column names.

Comment: Should have added `BEGIN ATOMIC` probably does not mean what you think it does. See here [Create Function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) at the 'sql_body The body of a LANGUAGE SQL function. This can either be a single statement ...' section.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver 1) Have gotten the impression that it's considered preferable when possible (e.g. re: dependency tracking); 2) Good to know, think that was an example of what I mean when I say I have trouble separating the wheat from the chaff re: trying to look up syntax; 3) Okay, can get over myself and do that if I have to but was hoping I didn't, thank you; 4) That clears some things up that I was struggling with in the documentation on my own I think, yes!

Comment: `sql` functions are limited in what they can do. Basically  you can  pass parameters to a SQL query or queries. If you can express everything in SQL then they work.  If you want to anything more involved(loops, nested conditionals,etc) you will end up using `plpgsql` or one of the other procedural languages.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Clarifying question: "define variable based on passed parameter" counts as "more involved" in and of itself? (Putting aside the conditionals for a sec for the sake of getting this through my head.) If so that explains one of the things that had been going over my head before but I want to be completely sure instead of assuming, apologies if I just sound dense.

Comment: I am not sure what you are getting at? The best thing to do is for `sql` functions/procedures is read [Sql Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html) and for `plpgsql` read [plpgsql function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html). Then set up test functions  in both to see how the syntax/processes work.

Comment: You are confused about syntax. You write a function in language SQL, but actually use constructs from PL/pgSQL like `IF` and `DECLARE`. I recommend reading the documentation more thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

> because I don't know what other languages the database is currently set up for

All supported Postgres versions always include PL/pgSQL.

If you want to use procedural elements like variables or conditional statements like `IF` you need PL/pgSQL. So your procedure has to be defined with `language plpgsql` - that removes the possibility to use the ANSI standard `BEGIN ATOMIC` syntax.

> Don't know how to compensate for Postgres's not differentiating variables and parameters from column names at all.

You don't. Most people simply using naming conventions to do that. In my environment we use `p_` for parameters and `l_` for "local" variables. Use whatever you prefer.

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-VAR-SUBST)

> By default, PL/pgSQL will report an error if a name in an SQL statement could refer to either a variable or a table column. You can fix such a problem by renaming the variable or column, or by qualifying the ambiguous reference, or by telling PL/pgSQL which interpretation to prefer.
>
> The simplest solution is to rename the variable or column. A common coding rule is to use a different naming convention for PL/pgSQL variables than you use for column names. For example, if you consistently name function variables v_something while none of your column names start with v_, no conflicts will occur.

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html)  the body for a procedure written in PL/pgSQL (or any other language that is not SQL) must be provided as a string. This is typically done using [dollar quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) to make writing the source easier.

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW), if you want to store the result of a single row query in a variable, use `select ... into from ...`.

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS) an `IF` statement needs a `THEN`

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) there is no `TOP` clause in Postgres (or standard SQL). Use `limit` or the standard compliant `fetch first 1 rows only` instead.

To avoid a clash between names of variables and column names, most people use some kind of prefix for parameters and variables. This also helps to identify them in the code.

In Postgres it's usually faster to use NOT EXISTS instead of NOT IN.

In Postgres statements are terminated with `;`. `GO` isn't a SQL command in SQL Server either - it's a client side thing supported by SSMS. To my knowledge, there is no SQL tool that works with Postgres that supports the `GO` "batch terminator" the same way SSMS does.

So a direct translation of your T-SQL code to PL/pgSQL could look like this:

```
create or replace procedure add_identities_to_groups(p_group_name text default NULL) 
language plpgsql 
as
$$ --<< start of PL/pgSQL code 

declare --<< start a block for all variables
  l_use_group_id integer;
begin  --<< start the actual code

  if p_group_name is NULL THEN --<< then required
    select id 
      into l_use_group_id
    from user_groups ug
    where not exists (select * from group_identities gi where gi.id = ug.user_id)
    order by ug.id asc
    limit 1;
  ELSE 
    select id 
      into l_use_group_id 
    from user_groups  
    where name = p_group_name;
  end if;
  
  insert into group_identities (group_id, user_id)
  select l_use_group_id, id 
  from user_identities ui
  where not exists (select * from group_identities gi where gi.user_id = ui.id);
END;
$$
;
```